# Wait for a Flowfile to be picked only after the previous flowfile has been processed completely

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flowfile that is a list of files,

[image]

that gets split into individual flowfiles (10 in this case), this is given as input to FetchSFTP processor to fetch the file from a sftp location, the content of this fetched file is then split and is processed and stored.

**In this example:** I want to start processing ep.txt only after i have processed bulk.txt after that names.txt and so on.

I was referring to these links:

https://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/

and

https://pierrevillard.com/2018/06/27/nifi-workflow-monitoring-wait-notify-pattern-with-split-and-merge/

I was able to implement something like this.
[image]

but this is not what I was looking for, I want to implement a wait before fetchSFTP

[image]

I tried release signal identifier with filename , but that was stopping any flowfile from moving forward.

Please advise, thank you

Comment: How is the file to be processed after all the other ones selected?

Comment: This is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvJx8vQnCNE&lc=UgzHBAI-4X3vn_dWSHV4AaABAg.9ssoo7vzq1d9ssqH-c7ttL

All I had to do was to group the processors set its concurrency configuration to **single flowfile per node** and outbound policy to **Batch Output**
With this configuration the FileProcessor(in my screenshot) group will take the next flowfile  only after completely processing the flowfile that is already inside the group.

[image]

[image]

Inside the group.

[image]